# I'm struggling to understand how, in an categorical multiple regression, adding in a continuous variable can change the beta p-values

Tags: regression, anova, categorical-data, p-value

So I ran a regression with an outcome variable (CSI) and a categorical predictor variable (RT) than has two levels (A and B). I made A my baseline variable, and found that the difference between A and B was significant p = .001.

CSI ~ RT

Then I added in a continuous predictor variable (ACI), without an interaction.

CSI ~ RT + ACI

I made A my baseline variable again, and found that the difference between A and B was significant p = .003.

My understanding is that if you have a categorical variable as a predictor in a regression, it's an ANOVA, and so basically the 'slopes' of A and B are flat (they're just the means). But when I add in a continuous predictor (ACI), all of the slopes go from being flat to being whatever ACI is. What I'm confused about is that, since there is no interaction, the slopes are all the same. If the slopes are all the same, then the distance between each group (A and B) is the same at every level of the continuous predictor variable (ACI), including the means of the groups. Which means that the means did not change, and so the difference between the means in the first model (CSI ~ RT) are the same distance apart as in the second model (CSI ~ RT + ACI). So what could be changing the p-value of the difference between the betas of A and B if the distance between the means didn't change? Did adding in ACI alter the way that the model partitioned the variance or something? Does adding in ACI change the value of the standard error of the beta coefficients??

Comment: Consider the situation where CSI is a multiple of ACI but otherwise CSI is unrelated to RT.  The first p-value will be around $0.5$ while the second must be $0$ because it achieves a perfect fit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by 'CSI' is a multiple of ACI'

Comment: We say a vector $x$ is a multiple of another vector $y$ when there is a number $a$ for which $x = ay.$